# How to view the files/directories created by my iOS app in Xcode

Tags: ios, file, directory

I have an app and I want to examine the files and directories the app creates on my iPhone in Xcode 9.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean to get the file path ?

Comment: yes, i am working on an project which I took over from a collegue and I need to check if and where this app is storing files

Comment: I have posted the answer in objective c, if your project is in swift i can help you with it in my answer.

Comment: In Android one can examine the files and folders of an app with the IDE. Is there such way in Xcode?

Comment: No direct way is provided to access files in iPhones from Xcode. To copy files to Mac, what we can do is to create files in Document directory and make the directory visible from itunes. Then you can copy them to your Mac. Not convenient, though...

Comment: If you are using an emulator, you can check access that folder from your mac.
I don't see a way of accessing a folder inside your phone though.

Answer (score 14):

Go to:

Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Select your device -> Select your app

Use the "gear" icon and "Download Container".
Save this file in any location you like and access it by right clicking the file and "Show Package Content"

This will reveal the files that are saved in your app's document directory and other folders within the app. This will not self update on your next run, of course.

If you are using a simulator, you may access the contents folder by going to :
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/

Answer (score 5):

If you have a physical device you can add **UIFileSharingEnabled** key in info.plist and set it value to **YES**

then run your app

open iTunes select device and goto file sharing and select your app you will be shown files created by your app

and if you don't have a physical device then only option you have is Fiona's answer

Answer (score 4):

You can view your directories in your physical device too. To do so, just add two keys in your info.plist file

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/> 

<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

> **UIFileSharingEnabled** key will enable "Application supports iTunes file sharing"
>
> **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace** key will enable "Supports
> opening documents in place"

Then go your physical device's files to see your folder(s). cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Populator"];
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Files"];
NSLog(@"Source Path: %@\n Documents Path: %@ \n Folder Path: %@", sourcePath, documentsDirectory, folderPath);
```

This will get you the file path. Now in your Desktop 
Open Finder, press `Shift + Command + G`, paste the path and press Go.

Comment: Is there no way to check without writing code? Because I don't know the names of files / directories created by the app?

Comment: All the files are written in the respective app containers. There is no way to know the path of each and every file without writing this code. Or else, browse to the container folder and browse the files randomly.

Comment: Oh I see... This actually means, I need to know the file name?

Comment: What if I don't know the directory name, ie. "Populator"? How can I retrieve a list of ALL saved files?